# Tricky Question on using Data Loader to perform 'update' on Accounts

Tags: data-loader

So I have a csv file which needs to update Accounts on Salesforce.

Here's my question I have 138 different phone/product types(in the csv file) and each Account in the csv has more than one phone/product types with quantities(column). So how can I create a picklist in the salesforce if I had to select more than one types and provide the quantities ?

If I use multi picklist I will be able to select more than one product type but how will I specify its respective quantities ?

Example: Account1 has Type -Phone1 and Phone2  and quatity - for phone1 -3; for phone2 - 4

Comment: Sounds like you should create an 'AccountLineItem' child object and load that.

Comment: Thanks Adrian I understood what you were saying. +1 to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go with creating the 'AccountLineItem' child object as Adrian suggested, you would have to create a new object with a look-up or master-detail relationship with the Account object. When using the data loader, you would need to do two updates - one for the accounts, and one for the 'AccountLineItem' with the proper account Id in the reference field.